# GTK+ Application: Receive input from a worker thread

Tags: gtk, signals, emit

I have a GTK+ application with a GtkTextBuffer. It uses several worker threads which perform some lengthy operations. Those threads can report their progress in a textual format. I want to show details on how a worker thread is performing. Can you please tell me how to receive input from a worker thread?

I thought that I can emit a signal "insert-text" from the worker thread, but cannot find a relevant example while googling. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What can't you find an example of?

Comment: An example of how to fire a signal from a worker thread. Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: It's the same as emitting a signal from the main thread - `g_signal_emit()` or `g_signal_emit_by_name()`. The signal handler is called from the main thread with the GDK lock held.

Comment: @ptomato, are you sure g_signal_emit lock is handler by Gtk ? if that's right, then what he says should do it.

Comment: @erick2red It works for me. I didn't understand the OP's question to mean that it didn't work, just that he/she couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GAsyncQueue](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) for messaging between your UI and your workers thread, it is a very finished API for communication.

Comment: I had a look at the API (thanks for suggesting that). However, it is not obvious to me how to push signals through the main loop. Puling for them (either by means of a timer or an idle processing) is inefficient. I just would like to get informed when something interesting has happened. That's why I thought about firing signals from the worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

Classic quick and dirty: Write your status updates to a linked list (protected by some sync primitive), have the GTK main loop poll it via a timer.